# Find $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ but for all $\epsilon >0$, $f$ is not in $L^{p+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $p \geq 1$, find a function $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$, $f$ is not in $L^{p+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: This is a standard problem that appears in many textbooks; what have you tried, and where are you having trouble? Do you know examples of functions in $L^1$ that aren't in $L^2$? Or other failures of inclusion? (-1) and voting to close: this is not a do-my-homework site.

Comment: @Bongers: Do you read the question carefully? It's $L^{p+\epsilon}$ for all $\epsilon$. I know many examples of function in $L^1$ but not in $L^2$ such as $1/x^a$- form.

Comment: Yes, I did read your (one sentence long) question carefully. A good starting point is a function which is in $L^1$ and not $L^2$; then redo with $L^1$ but not $L^{1.5}$; then redo with $L^1$ but not $L^{1.25}$; then redo... which leads us back to the question of whether you tried anything before posting.

Comment: You said it is a problem in many textbooks. Could you show one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: For every $n>0$ construct $f_n\in L^1$ such that the support is contained in $(-1,1)$ and $f_n\notin L^{1+1/n}$. Rescale these functions in a proper way and patch them together, show that it has the desired properties.